# Pandas DataFrames, Series and id (in CPython)

Tags: python, pandas, memory

When I run the code below, the value of `id(df.c1)` changes from initialization after assigning to `df.c2`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2), (3, 4)], columns=['c1', 'c2'])
print("(before df.c2 assignment) id(df.c1):{0} and id(df):{1}".format(id(df.c1), id(df)))
df.c2 = 20
print("(after df.c2 assignment) id(df.c1):{0} and id(df):{1}".format(id(df.c1), id(df)))
```

One sample run produces:

```
(before df.c2 assignment) id(df.c1):4440267968 and id(df):4402796528
(after df.c2 assignment) id(df.c1):4440267016 and id(df):4402796528
```

Based on the [documentation for `id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), it seems that `id` is constant during an object's lifetime, which would hint to me that `df.c1` is being changed despite not assigning to it. I think this might be due to some pandas internals (e.g. the block manager), but I don't know enough about pandas to quickly determine this.

If this is the case, is there a "safe" counterpart to `id` that I could use for pandas objects? I need to keep track of objects for an instrumentation task.

Python version: Python 3.6.3

Pandas version: 0.20.2

EDIT:
I think one possible workaround is to use the `ctypes.data` for the underlying numpy array in the dataframe series. This does not seem to have the same issue.